# Not able use Grouping by in my class Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I am trying to learn Java-8  and I am getting this issue.
I have an entity class with 2 fields

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "sample_name")
public class OutsourceModelToProcess extends xyz {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "XXX", referencedColumnName = "YYY" )
    private OutsourceModel outsourceModel;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "AAA", referencedColumnName = "BBB")
    private Processes processes;

}
```

so I wanted a map like `Map<OutsourceModel, List<Process<Processes>>`, because one outsource model can have a list of processes.
so I wrote the code like so

```java
Map<OutsourceModel, List<Processes>> mapOfOutSourceModelUuidToListOfProcesses = outsourceModelToProcessList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        OutsourceModelToProcess::getOutsourceModel,
        Collectors.mapping(
            OutsourceModelToProcess::getProcesses,
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    ));
```

but this line never executes even after 10 min.
So I ran it again in debugger mode and evaluated the expression on IntelliJ using the calculator symbol.
I got this error: "bad method type alias"

I am new to Java 8 and am not getting where I am going wrong. Any help appreciated thanks.

But when I replace the key with a String it works properly.

```
Map<String,List<Processes>> mapOfOutSourceModelUuidToListOfProcesses = outsourceModelToProcessList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        o -> o.getOutsourceModel().getUuid(), 
        Collectors.mapping(
            OutsourceModelToProcess::getProcesses,
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    ));
```

but I want like the first one...

Comment: I think your problem with IntelliJ is because you're using Lombok to generate the getters. For whatever reason, probably a bug/lack of support in the Lombok plugin, the debugger's expression evaluator is not able to find the method Lombok generates. So for the purposes of debugging, remove Lombok and write the getters yourself (you can use delombok to do it). You can reinstate lombok when it's working.

Comment: um i dont think there is an issue with lombok as it works if i replace the key with a string class

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on “but this line never executes even after 10 min”? Do you mean a) this line is not executed (never reached) or b) this line is executed but does not complete within 10 minutes?

Comment: The second option-b .This line is reached but does not complete execution. But if i replace the map key with the String , it works properly as per my requirment.But i dont want the string to be the key.I want the "OutSourceModel" to be the key.

Comment: Nothing that hints why the latter shall work and the former doesn't. Just as a hit and trial to drive similarity, can you try replacing `OutsourceModelToProcess::getOutsourceModel` with `o -> o.getOutsourceModel()`?

Comment: tried that too, the same thing happens(a warning comes up saying that I can do it directly without the lambda), but any ways the line doesent execute. Am i using the the  groupingBy property properly? Is there any mistake I am doing?

Comment: Does `Processes` or `OutsourceModel` contain a field of type `OutsourceModelToProcess`?